# Autocomplete for ARM GCC Specific Libraries

Tags: gui, automation, autocomplete, vim

I have been trying to find an autocomplete tool for quite some time now to no avail. Personally I would like this to work in vim but if some GUI tool can do the job then fine I will learn the GUI. Thank you for any suggestions

My Problem:
I am developing an arm application which references the device specific libraries in a separate directory (with header files). I have written my own make script for compilation which use arm-none-eabi-gcc as the compiler. These libraries have a huge index of function definitions (with a nice help file) but it's a pain to keep referencing the help file for exact function names. I am hoping that this autocomplete tool will be able to reference the libraries and make autocomplete solutions for functions in those header files instead of what most seem to do which is just autocomplete based on functions already in the file.

What I have tried:

You Complete Me: This one I honestly have the most hope for still. It seems like it should work but I think it compiles with clang and since I am using GCC it seems unable to parse the inclusion I give it in via the flags field. (I have checked with YcmDebugInfo and yes my -I directory is listed but auto completion just doesn't happen).

SuperTab: Only works with local files from what I can tell.

Sublime: Only works with files that are already open (this library has ~20 header files I can not just open all the library headers to make autocomplete work that is not silly).